# How to set java -classpath for two directories?

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to get a little test working in Java. I have two directories `root` and `root/lib`. I have a `root/lib/Test.java` file and a `root/Foo.java` file. I can compile both with `javac lib/Test.java` and then `javac -classpath lib Foo.java` and get:

```
root/
 Foo.java
 Foo.class
 lib/
  Test.java
  Test.class
```

here is how they look like:

```
class Foo {
  static public void main(String[] argv) {
    System.out.println(Test.test());
  }
}
```

and

```
class Test {
  public static int test() {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

How do I run them so they work together without adding a import statement? I have tried `java -classpath ".;lib" Foo` but I just get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Foo`

```
Lala: jeena$ cd root
Lala:root jeena$ java -classpath ".;lib" Foo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Foo
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Foo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This suggests that you're in the parent of root:

> javac -classpath root/lib Foo.java

And this suggests that you're in root:

> java -classpath ".;lib" Foo

Which directory are you actually working from? Perhaps absolute paths would be easier for you?

Also, what operating system? On Linux, for example, your path separator will be `:` instead of `;`.

Comment: It is Linux and OS X I was trying it on. I actually was within root, perhaps I should rewrite the question a little bit.

Comment: Oh ah! Ok now I get it, I should use ":" instead of ";" thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the actual problem is - if you're on windows, and neither class uses a specific package name (i.e., they're in the unnamed package, which you shouldn't use), then "java -classpath .;lib Foo" should be able to load and run Foo without a problem.

If they're not in the same package (which you haven't shown) then as long as Test is public, you can access the test() method by using "packageName.goes.here.Test.test()."

Comment: They are just plain java files without package and I've tried to do `java -classpath ".;lib" Foo` on both Linux and OS X and on both I get the NoClassDefFoundError. I have uploaded the files with my filestructure here: http://jeena.net/t/java-test.zip

Comment: (When I use it without the quotes around .;lib then the shell gets all crazy because it thinks lib is the next command which follows, which it isn't.)

Comment: @Jeena You're using the wrong path separator, as I explained.

Comment: Ah, you never specified Linux or OSX, which is why *I* specified Windows - the ; is the path separator for Windows and not UNIX-like OSes.

Comment: Ah yeah you're right, every example I saw used ; instad of : so I assumed that is the way java does it, thank you!